# How to edit or call this jQuery function to work on a vanilla JavaScript onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to edit or call this jQuery .click() function to use it **as a regular or vanilla JavaScript onmouseout**:

```
$("#copystuff").click(function() {
  var temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append(temp);

  var previewHeader = $("#PreviewHeader").text();
  var HiddenURLdiv = $("#HiddenURLdiv").text();
  var contentTogether = previewHeader + "\n" + HiddenURLdiv;

  temp.val(contentTogether).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#thecopiedtext").text(contentTogether);
  temp.remove();
});
```

This is because I need to first randomize the content of one div with an onclick function which is working perfectly fine already so please don't focus on this, but then copy its content together with the content of a second div which I can do perfectly fine with this jQuery function already, but I need this second step to be achieve it with a JavaScript onmouseout to have all this job done in one single click, like this:

- onclick randomize one div content (solved, so skip it),
- onmouseout copy both div's content.

because **changing the .click event of this jQuery to .mouseout or .mouseleave or .mousemove only triggers the printing (append) function, but not the copy one**. Actually the copy function only happens after a click is done in all cases.

Long story short: **I just need this jQuery function to be performed by a regular or vanilla JavaScript onmouseout, either editing or calling this jQuery**.

*Or maybe make the following mouseout event to actually copy without clicking its element:*

```
$("#copystuff").mouseout(function() {
  var temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append(temp);

  var previewHeader = $("#PreviewHeader").text();
  var HiddenURLdiv = $("#HiddenURLdiv").text();
  var contentTogether = previewHeader + "\n" + HiddenURLdiv;

  temp.val(contentTogether).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#thecopiedtext").text(contentTogether);
  temp.remove();
});
```

These are my two vanilla JavaScripts functions:

- onclick="randomize(divone)"
- **onmouseout="copyText(bothdivs)"**  <-- the one I need to use this jQuery

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: You already have the function, you just need to give it a name: `function copystuff() { ... }`. Now assign it as `mouseout` event handler.

Comment: Thank you  Chris G. I'm sorry for my ignorance. How do I assign it as an onmouseout?

Comment: Also looking at your comments to the answers you got, I'm not sure what you're asking tbh. `onmouseout` is the event when the mouse moves away from an element, no longer hovering above it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes Chris G, that is exactly what I need: When the mouse moves away from the element. But I need this on a regular JavaScript onmouseout. These are my two JavaScripts functions: onclick="copyText(divone)" and onmouseout="copyText(divtwo)" How should I make them work with your suggestions?

Comment: You're looking for this I guess? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/o5vybxde/

Comment: Thank you very much Chris G. Apparently this will work. I'll try to adjust it to my project and will let you. Thank you also for the time you take to code it in such a detailed way. I appreciate a lot your kindness.

Comment: No, Chris G. I'm sorry, this is not what I meant. I have solved the first step which is a regular JavaScript onclick. That is not the problem at all. **All that I need is this jQuery I posted in the question to be performed or called by a regular JavaScript onmouseout.** Just like that. Nothing else. **How to perform this jQuery as regular JavaScript onmouseout="something()" function?** This jQuery is able to copy the content of 2 different div's simultaneously by one single click, which I want to be preformed as a regular JavaScript onmouseout.

Comment: When you go to the fiddle and move the mouse over the indicated area, then *move it back out*, the text of two divs is combined and copied to the clipboard, as per the mouseleave handler that calls the function

Comment: To be clear: what you call "this jQuery" is two things: 90% of it is an anonymous function that takes the text of two specific divs and puts it in the clipboard, and the wrapper is assigning that function as handler for the click event of `#copystuff`. Both things use jQuery but could be converted to 100% vanilla JS. Since I want to a) use the function multiple times and b) specify one of the two divs when calling it I a) isolated and named the function and b) added a param. Then I'm setting it as handler for a click and a mouseleave event.

Comment: I suspect we're talking past each other because you're using weird terminology. Using inline `onmouseout="something()"` instead of external `addEventListener('mouseout', something)` is not really a JS vs. jQuery thing. Anyway, I'll edit my fiddle to what I assume you're looking for (although inline code is bad practice)

Comment: Thank you again Chris G , but I don't need to copy both <h1> separately one from a click and one from a mouseout. I just want to copy both <h1> or in my case both <div> simultaneously in a mouseout event. I don't think it is weird language at all as you suggest. Vanilla or old JavaScript uses the function onmouseout before Javasript libraries came to the scene. The reason I'm looking to inline code practice is because changing the .click event in this script to .mouseout does not copy the content of both <div>, it just print (append) the text to the document... (I'll continue on next message)

Comment: ...To copy that content I need to click, which conflicts with my need of having all events done by a single click event, as I explained on detail at the question I posted. Please be so kind to take a look at it again, as I edited the question to make it easier to understand, I suppose. Thank you for your help and kindness. And also for your patience. Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the text appearing in your document (but that's what happens if the function breaks after appending the textarea), however in Firefox, as I just found out, I apparently cannot copy text to the clipboard in a mouseleave event. I get a warning in the console about `document.copy` can only be called in short event handlers following user events (this is for security reasons) and apparently mouseleave/mouseout is no such event

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts, Chris. I really appreciate all your support. I probably need to think in a different approach for this. Please let me know if you get something useful. I'll be around searching for alternatives. I'm very grateful with you.

Answer (score 0):

I would simulate onClick event on it like this:

```
document.querySelector("your element here").click()
```

Try using it like this:

Element 1 is the element that has mouseout (mouseleave) event, and element 2 is the element that you want to be clicked, the one that calls what you need.

```
document.querySelector("element 1").addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
   document.querySelector("element 2").click();
});
```

You can even try changing "mouseleave" with "mouseout"

Implementing my solution with your code:

```
document.querySelector("you put some element here that you want to add mouseleave event to").addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
   document.querySelector("#copystuff").click();
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I'm sorry but I thought my question was clear. Sorry if not. I need to use or call this jQuery as **a regular JavaScript onmouseout**.

Comment: I edited my question to do mouseleave in "normal" javascript. Is it helpful now?

Comment: Nothing. I can not make this to work. no matter how much I try. These are my two JavaScripts functions: onclick="copyText(divone)" and onmouseout="copyText(divtwo)" How should I make them work with your code?

Comment: Do you mind to type the full jQuery function, and also the regular JavaScript onmouseout function that I should use to call this jQuery?

Comment: Just add this under the code that you provided in question. Is that ok?

Comment: I did add it. Now how I call it ?  These are my two JavaScripts functions: onclick="copyText(divone)" and onmouseout="copyText(divtwo)" How should I make them work with your code? What should I substitute in them?

Comment: How??? Your profile says: Apparently, Jon Nezbit prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Comment: Learning. I thought this was easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunc = () => {
  var temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append(temp);

  var previewHeader = $("#PreviewHeader").text();
  var HiddenURLdiv = $("#HiddenURLdiv").text();
  var contentTogether = previewHeader + "\n" + HiddenURLdiv;

  temp.val(contentTogether).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#thecopiedtext").text(contentTogether);
  temp.remove();
}

$("#copystuff").click(myFunc).mouseout(myFunc);
```

Edit

```
const myFunc = () => {
  var temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append(temp);

  var previewHeader = $("#PreviewHeader").text();
  var HiddenURLdiv = $("#HiddenURLdiv").text();
  var contentTogether = previewHeader + "\n" + HiddenURLdiv;

  temp.val(contentTogether).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#thecopiedtext").text(contentTogether);
  temp.remove();
}

$("#copystuff").click(myFunc);

document.getElementById('copystuff').onmouseout = function(){
  this.click()
};
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed ElMetwally. Now I'm very confused. Isn't this option calling the same function on both click and mouseout events?

Comment: You are welcome dear, yes. when click will calling myFunc(). and when mouseout will calling myFunc()

Comment: But just I need to use or call this jQuery as **a regular JavaScript onmouseout.**

Comment: I edited my solution. please try and confirm with me.

Comment: I can not make my onmouseout="()" function to work with this.
I tried different ways and none of them works. How should I call this function with my onmouseout? These are my two JavaScripts functions: onclick="copyText(divone)" and onmouseout="copyText(divtwo)" How should I make them work with your code?