# Copy more than one div to clipboard and adding characters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the following script to copy a div to clipboard.  But I am trying to copy multiple divs (**DivA + DivB**) with the same button, while adding some quotes and brackets around each div.  I saw some answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774738/copy-multiple-texts-from-multiple-divs-in-clipboard), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420412/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-two-divs-to-the-clipboard-at-one-time)), but I can't seem to be able to implement them to the current script.

So the output should be like:

```
"A certain quote" (Author Name).
```

---

This is the current script to copy one div.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">
<p>A certain quote</p>
</div>

<div id="divB">
<p>Author Name</p>
</div>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#divA')">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're only reading the text from '#divA', as that's the selector passed to the `copyToClipboard()` function.

To do what you require amend the logic to create a string in the format you require containing the text of both `#divA` and `#divB`:

```js
let $divA = $('#divA');
let $divB = $('#divB');

$('button').on('click', e => {
  copyToClipboard(`"${$divA.text().trim()}" (${$divB.text().trim()}).`);
});

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">
  <p>A certain quote</p>
</div>
<div id="divB">
  <p>Author Name</p>
</div>
<button type="button">Copy</button><br /><br />

Paste here to test:<br />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Why when I test it here it doesn't work? https://jsfiddle.net/kv3dw8mz/

Comment: It doesn't work in that fiddle because you've removed the last `}` so there's a syntax error